# What's wrong with this LL(1) grammar?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers

I am trying to build a LL(1) parse table for the following grammar:

```
S -> L
L -> L : L
L -> id R
R -> ( L )
R -> ( )
R -> Epsilon
```

There are two problems here. First, the `L` rules are a left recursion and the `R` rules have `(` as the same prefix.

So I modified the Grammar to this one:

```
S -> L
L -> id R X
X -> : L X
X -> Epsilon
R -> ( P
R -> Epsilon
P -> L )
P -> )
```

I then checked the grammar with the JFLAP Tool and it says that my grammar is not LL(1). But I just don't see the problem.

Can somebody help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original grammar is ambiguous:

```
L → L : L
L → id R
```

Suppose we have `id : id : id`. (For simplicity, I'm just letting `R` derive the empty string, but any valid derivation of the `R`s would end up with the same ambiguity.) That needs to be derived from `S → L → L1 : L2`, but from there, either `L1` or `L2` can derive `L : L`. In effect, the two cases correspond to `:` associating to the left or associating to the right, but with longer sequences of `:`-separated `id R` clauses, the number of possible parses increases exponentially.

Your rewrite does not eliminate this ambiguity, it just makes it harder to see.

In short, you need to decide how `:` associates. It probably makes most sense for it to associate to the left, but an LL grammar really only handles right-association. (That's not a huge problem since you can reassociate the AST easily enough, but with an LR parser generator you wouldn't have to do any of this.) If we rewrite `L` as right-associative, we automatically eliminate the left-recursion problem:

```
S  → L
L  → L'
L  → L' : L
L' → id R
```

(Really, `L'` is not very useful in this case; it would have been almost as simple to write `L → id R | id R L`. But in either case, you end up needing to factor out the common prefix.)

Comment: Hi rici. Thanks for your answer. I understand you wrote and entered it into Jflap, but it still says that the grammar is not LL(1). is the tool reliable?

Comment: @adelpoint: actually, i did not try it with any tool. So I might have missed another problem.

Comment: Thanks anyway. It helped me understand the Problem better :)

Comment: @AdelPoint: Looking at it, I realize that my change introduces another shared prefix which needs to be factored out. I really don't see the point to LL grammar generators, personally; excellent LR generators are available and IMHO you don't need to think nearly as hard about grammars to write an LR-parseable grammar. YMMV.